# How do you hook up a Module thats loaded dynamically in the PureMVC framework for ActionScript 3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, puremvc

I'm using the PureMVC framework on a FlexBuilder 3 project.  I have already hooked up the ApplicationFacade and have executed simple commands successfully.

I have a ModuleLoader in my entry point Application.mxml and I set the url of the ModuleLoader when the user logs in from the ApplicationMdiator.

Where do I register my module mediator that gets dynamically loaded when the url is set because I don't have an instance available from the ApplicationMediator?

Do I need to create another facade for the Module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PureMVC comes in two flavours for ActionScript 3 PureMVC Standard and PureMVC Multicore respectively.

You will need to use the PureMVC Multicore version if you want to use modules in a flex application.

A good reference explanation with linked demos can be found [here](http://puremvc.org/content/view/75/181/)